# Joomla backend not reflecting updated PHP version

Tags: php, upgrade, php7, versions

I've updated to PHP 7.2.17 through my host's cpanel, but I'm still getting a message in the Joomla backend that my PHP version is not updated.

> Error
>
> We have detected that your server is using PHP 7.0.31 which is
>   obsolete and no longer receives official security updates by its
>   developers. The Joomla! Project recommends upgrading your site to PHP
>   7.1 or later which will receive security updates at least until 2019-12-01. Please ask your host to make PHP 7.1 or a later version
>   the default version for your site. If your host is already PHP 7.1
>   ready please enable PHP 7.1 on your site's root and 'administrator'
>   directories – typically you can do this yourself through a tool in
>   your hosting control panel, but it's best to ask your host if you are
>   unsure.

Any help to reflect correct PHP version in Joomla would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you select the new PHP version through the PHP Selector or the Multi-PHP options in cPanel? Normally only one or the other will have the effect of changing the PHP you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your .htaccess file to see what version of PHP was added via cPanel. Depending on the host it is usually reflected in either .htaccess or a php.ini file in the root of your directory. Just modify that file to the version you want and it should fix things.

Also if you have a server running SuperCacher or an equivalent file caching module, clear that cache and it may resolve the issue.